# Facebook registration plugin security/https error

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the Facebook Registration Plugin on my site, but I'm getting security errors in Firefox (10) and Safari (5).

I have this code in HTML:

```
<fb:registration fields="[{'name':'name'}, {'name':'email'}, {'name':'company', 'description':'company', 'type':'text'}]" redirect-uri="http://[url removed]/" width="318" height="360"></fb:registration>
```

So the redirect-uri is in http. I insert the JS SDK with the code provided by Facebook:

```
(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "http://connect.facebook.net/" + language + "/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=107844832676140";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

Everything works fine in Chrome and IE9, but I get a security warning in Firefox and Safari. In Firefox I get this error message:

*"Although this page is encrypted, the information you have entered is to be sent over an unencrypted connection and could easily be read by a third party.
Are you sure you want to continue sending this information?"*

In both Firefox and Safari I can press ok and go ahead with posting the form. But how do I get rid of this security message? Does the page I am posting to need to be in https?

Comment: I checked the documentation but found no direct answer: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/advanced/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a problem with http and https.

My guess is that your page is over https, but in your code you load the facebook sdk over http, which is not a good idea...

change this:

```
js.src = "http://connect.facebook.net/" + language + "/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=107844832676140";
```

to this:

```
js.src = document.location.protocol + "//connect.facebook.net/" + language + "/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=107844832676140";
```

Comment: The page is in http. Also tried your solution, but the problems still persists.

Comment: The security message you are getting is caused when the browser loads a page over https, but has **at least** one request that is sent over http, it can be anything from an image, script or style file. If in fact you have nothing in https then you should not face this security message, since you do I'm guessing that you're loading something in https.

Answer (score 1):

Developers complain of getting security warnings in browsers like Firefox and safari. For instance, Firefox gives security warning like -

> Although this page is encrypted, the information you have entered is to be sent over an unencrypted connection and could easily be read by a third party. Are you sure you want to continue sending this information?

User can press ok and go ahead with posting the form. However, web developer do not want users' to avoid registration because of this securty warning.

For solution Please refer to: 
http://blog.oursocion.com/2012/07/facebook-registration-plugin.html